# How can I make this code do its function with every value on array? (Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My current code:

```
function GetDrops() {
    // Sheets Variables
    var mobItemDB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var mobDB = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('mobDB')
    var itemDB = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('itemDB')
    var itemDBLastRow = itemDB.getLastRow()
    var itemDBLastColumn = itemDB.getLastColumn()
    var itemArray = itemDB.getRange(8,1,itemDBLastRow-7,itemDBLastColumn).getValues()
    var healing = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('0 Healing')
    var usable = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('2-11-18 Usable')
    var loot = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('3 Loot')
    var armor = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('4a Armor')
    var shield = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('4b Shield')
    var headgear = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('4c Headgear')
    var garment = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('4d Garment')
    var footgear = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('4e Footgear')
    var accessory = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('4f Accessory')
    var weapons = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('5 Weapons')
    var cards = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('6 Cards')
    var eggs = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('7 Eggs')
    var petArmor = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('8 Pet Armor')
    var ammo = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('10 Ammo')
    
    // ######################################## All Drop Cells ########################################
    var dropsA = mobDB.getRange(3, 37, 101, 26).getValues();
    var dropsB = [dropsA[0][0], dropsA[0][2], dropsA[0][4], dropsA[0][6], dropsA[0][8], dropsA[0][10], dropsA[0][12], dropsA[0][14], dropsA[0][16], dropsA[0][18], dropsA[0][20], dropsA[0][22], dropsA[0][24],
                dropsA[1][0], dropsA[1][2], dropsA[1][4], dropsA[1][6], dropsA[1][8], dropsA[1][10], dropsA[1][12], dropsA[1][14], dropsA[1][16], dropsA[1][18], dropsA[1][20], dropsA[1][22], dropsA[1][24],
                dropsA[2][0], dropsA[2][2], dropsA[2][4], dropsA[2][6], dropsA[2][8], dropsA[2][10], dropsA[2][12], dropsA[2][14], dropsA[2][16], dropsA[2][18], dropsA[2][20], dropsA[2][22], dropsA[2][24],
                dropsA[3][0], dropsA[3][2], dropsA[3][4], dropsA[3][6], dropsA[3][8], dropsA[3][10], dropsA[3][12], dropsA[3][14], dropsA[3][16], dropsA[3][18], dropsA[3][20], dropsA[3][22], dropsA[3][24],
                dropsA[4][0], dropsA[4][2], dropsA[4][4], dropsA[4][6], dropsA[4][8], dropsA[4][10], dropsA[4][12], dropsA[4][14], dropsA[4][16], dropsA[4][18], dropsA[4][20], dropsA[4][22], dropsA[4][24],
                dropsA[5][0], dropsA[5][2], dropsA[5][4], dropsA[5][6], dropsA[5][8], dropsA[5][10], dropsA[5][12], dropsA[5][14], dropsA[5][16], dropsA[5][18], dropsA[5][20], dropsA[5][22], dropsA[5][24],
                dropsA[6][0], dropsA[6][2], dropsA[6][4], dropsA[6][6], dropsA[6][8], dropsA[6][10], dropsA[6][12], dropsA[6][14], dropsA[6][16], dropsA[6][18], dropsA[6][20], dropsA[6][22], dropsA[6][24],
                dropsA[7][0], dropsA[7][2], dropsA[7][4], dropsA[7][6], dropsA[7][8], dropsA[7][10], dropsA[7][12], dropsA[7][14], dropsA[7][16], dropsA[7][18], dropsA[7][20], dropsA[7][22], dropsA[7][24],
                dropsA[8][0], dropsA[8][2], dropsA[8][4], dropsA[8][6], dropsA[8][8], dropsA[8][10], dropsA[8][12], dropsA[8][14], dropsA[8][16], dropsA[8][18], dropsA[8][20], dropsA[8][22], dropsA[8][24],
                dropsA[9][0], dropsA[9][2], dropsA[9][4], dropsA[9][6], dropsA[9][8], dropsA[9][10], dropsA[9][12], dropsA[9][14], dropsA[9][16], dropsA[9][18], dropsA[9][20], dropsA[9][22], dropsA[9][24],
                dropsA[10][0], dropsA[10][2], dropsA[10][4], dropsA[10][6], dropsA[10][8], dropsA[10][10], dropsA[10][12], dropsA[10][14], dropsA[10][16], dropsA[10][18], dropsA[10][20], dropsA[10][22], dropsA[10][24],
                dropsA[11][0], dropsA[11][2], dropsA[11][4], dropsA[11][6], dropsA[11][8], dropsA[11][10], dropsA[11][12], dropsA[11][14], dropsA[11][16], dropsA[11][18], dropsA[11][20], dropsA[11][22], dropsA[11][24],
                dropsA[12][0], dropsA[12][2], dropsA[12][4], dropsA[12][6], dropsA[12][8], dropsA[12][10], dropsA[12][12], dropsA[12][14], dropsA[12][16], dropsA[12][18], dropsA[12][20], dropsA[12][22], dropsA[12][24],
                dropsA[13][0], dropsA[13][2], dropsA[13][4], dropsA[13][6], dropsA[13][8], dropsA[13][10], dropsA[13][12], dropsA[13][14], dropsA[13][16], dropsA[13][18], dropsA[13][20], dropsA[13][22], dropsA[13][24],
                dropsA[14][0], dropsA[14][2], dropsA[14][4], dropsA[14][6], dropsA[14][8], dropsA[14][10], dropsA[14][12], dropsA[14][14], dropsA[14][16], dropsA[14][18], dropsA[14][20], dropsA[14][22], dropsA[14][24],
                dropsA[15][0], dropsA[15][2], dropsA[15][4], dropsA[15][6], dropsA[15][8], dropsA[15][10], dropsA[15][12], dropsA[15][14], dropsA[15][16], dropsA[15][18], dropsA[15][20], dropsA[15][22], dropsA[15][24],
                dropsA[16][0], dropsA[16][2], dropsA[16][4], dropsA[16][6], dropsA[16][8], dropsA[16][10], dropsA[16][12], dropsA[16][14], dropsA[16][16], dropsA[16][18], dropsA[16][20], dropsA[16][22], dropsA[16][24],
                dropsA[17][0], dropsA[17][2], dropsA[17][4], dropsA[17][6], dropsA[17][8], dropsA[17][10], dropsA[17][12], dropsA[17][14], dropsA[17][16], dropsA[17][18], dropsA[17][20], dropsA[17][22], dropsA[17][24],
                dropsA[18][0], dropsA[18][2], dropsA[18][4], dropsA[18][6], dropsA[18][8], dropsA[18][10], dropsA[18][12], dropsA[18][14], dropsA[18][16], dropsA[18][18], dropsA[18][20], dropsA[18][22], dropsA[18][24],
                dropsA[19][0], dropsA[19][2], dropsA[19][4], dropsA[19][6], dropsA[19][8], dropsA[19][10], dropsA[19][12], dropsA[19][14], dropsA[19][16], dropsA[19][18], dropsA[19][20], dropsA[19][22], dropsA[19][24],
                dropsA[20][0], dropsA[20][2], dropsA[20][4], dropsA[20][6], dropsA[20][8], dropsA[20][10], dropsA[20][12], dropsA[20][14], dropsA[20][16], dropsA[20][18], dropsA[20][20], dropsA[20][22], dropsA[20][24],
                dropsA[21][0], dropsA[21][2], dropsA[21][4], dropsA[21][6], dropsA[21][8], dropsA[21][10], dropsA[21][12], dropsA[21][14], dropsA[21][16], dropsA[21][18], dropsA[21][20], dropsA[21][22], dropsA[21][24],
                dropsA[22][0], dropsA[22][2], dropsA[22][4], dropsA[22][6], dropsA[22][8], dropsA[22][10], dropsA[22][12], dropsA[22][14], dropsA[22][16], dropsA[22][18], dropsA[22][20], dropsA[22][22], dropsA[22][24],
                dropsA[23][0], dropsA[23][2], dropsA[23][4], dropsA[23][6], dropsA[23][8], dropsA[23][10], dropsA[23][12], dropsA[23][14], dropsA[23][16], dropsA[23][18], dropsA[23][20], dropsA[23][22], dropsA[23][24],
                dropsA[24][0], dropsA[24][2], dropsA[24][4], dropsA[24][6], dropsA[24][8], dropsA[24][10], dropsA[24][12], dropsA[24][14], dropsA[24][16], dropsA[24][18], dropsA[24][20], dropsA[24][22], dropsA[24][24],
                dropsA[25][0], dropsA[25][2], dropsA[25][4], dropsA[25][6], dropsA[25][8], dropsA[25][10], dropsA[25][12], dropsA[25][14], dropsA[25][16], dropsA[25][18], dropsA[25][20], dropsA[25][22], dropsA[25][24],
                dropsA[26][0], dropsA[26][2], dropsA[26][4], dropsA[26][6], dropsA[26][8], dropsA[26][10], dropsA[26][12], dropsA[26][14], dropsA[26][16], dropsA[26][18], dropsA[26][20], dropsA[26][22], dropsA[26][24],
                dropsA[27][0], dropsA[27][2], dropsA[27][4], dropsA[27][6], dropsA[27][8], dropsA[27][10], dropsA[27][12], dropsA[27][14], dropsA[27][16], dropsA[27][18], dropsA[27][20], dropsA[27][22], dropsA[27][24],
                dropsA[28][0], dropsA[28][2], dropsA[28][4], dropsA[28][6], dropsA[28][8], dropsA[28][10], dropsA[28][12], dropsA[28][14], dropsA[28][16], dropsA[28][18], dropsA[28][20], dropsA[28][22], dropsA[28][24],
                dropsA[29][0], dropsA[29][2], dropsA[29][4], dropsA[29][6], dropsA[29][8], dropsA[29][10], dropsA[29][12], dropsA[29][14], dropsA[29][16], dropsA[29][18], dropsA[29][20], dropsA[29][22], dropsA[29][24],
                dropsA[30][0], dropsA[30][2], dropsA[30][4], dropsA[30][6], dropsA[30][8], dropsA[30][10], dropsA[30][12], dropsA[30][14], dropsA[30][16], dropsA[30][18], dropsA[30][20], dropsA[30][22], dropsA[30][24],
                dropsA[31][0], dropsA[31][2], dropsA[31][4], dropsA[31][6], dropsA[31][8], dropsA[31][10], dropsA[31][12], dropsA[31][14], dropsA[31][16], dropsA[31][18], dropsA[31][20], dropsA[31][22], dropsA[31][24],
                dropsA[32][0], dropsA[32][2], dropsA[32][4], dropsA[32][6], dropsA[32][8], dropsA[32][10], dropsA[32][12], dropsA[32][14], dropsA[32][16], dropsA[32][18], dropsA[32][20], dropsA[32][22], dropsA[32][24],
                dropsA[33][0], dropsA[33][2], dropsA[33][4], dropsA[33][6], dropsA[33][8], dropsA[33][10], dropsA[33][12], dropsA[33][14], dropsA[33][16], dropsA[33][18], dropsA[33][20], dropsA[33][22], dropsA[33][24],
                dropsA[34][0], dropsA[34][2], dropsA[34][4], dropsA[34][6], dropsA[34][8], dropsA[34][10], dropsA[34][12], dropsA[34][14], dropsA[34][16], dropsA[34][18], dropsA[34][20], dropsA[34][22], dropsA[34][24],
                dropsA[35][0], dropsA[35][2], dropsA[35][4], dropsA[35][6], dropsA[35][8], dropsA[35][10], dropsA[35][12], dropsA[35][14], dropsA[35][16], dropsA[35][18], dropsA[35][20], dropsA[35][22], dropsA[35][24],
                dropsA[36][0], dropsA[36][2], dropsA[36][4], dropsA[36][6], dropsA[36][8], dropsA[36][10], dropsA[36][12], dropsA[36][14], dropsA[36][16], dropsA[36][18], dropsA[36][20], dropsA[36][22], dropsA[36][24],
                dropsA[37][0], dropsA[37][2], dropsA[37][4], dropsA[37][6], dropsA[37][8], dropsA[37][10], dropsA[37][12], dropsA[37][14], dropsA[37][16], dropsA[37][18], dropsA[37][20], dropsA[37][22], dropsA[37][24],
                dropsA[38][0], dropsA[38][2], dropsA[38][4], dropsA[38][6], dropsA[38][8], dropsA[38][10], dropsA[38][12], dropsA[38][14], dropsA[38][16], dropsA[38][18], dropsA[38][20], dropsA[38][22], dropsA[38][24],
                dropsA[39][0], dropsA[39][2], dropsA[39][4], dropsA[39][6], dropsA[39][8], dropsA[39][10], dropsA[39][12], dropsA[39][14], dropsA[39][16], dropsA[39][18], dropsA[39][20], dropsA[39][22], dropsA[39][24],
                dropsA[40][0], dropsA[40][2], dropsA[40][4], dropsA[40][6], dropsA[40][8], dropsA[40][10], dropsA[40][12], dropsA[40][14], dropsA[40][16], dropsA[40][18], dropsA[40][20], dropsA[40][22], dropsA[40][24],
                dropsA[41][0], dropsA[41][2], dropsA[41][4], dropsA[41][6], dropsA[41][8], dropsA[41][10], dropsA[41][12], dropsA[41][14], dropsA[41][16], dropsA[41][18], dropsA[41][20], dropsA[41][22], dropsA[41][24],
                dropsA[42][0], dropsA[42][2], dropsA[42][4], dropsA[42][6], dropsA[42][8], dropsA[42][10], dropsA[42][12], dropsA[42][14], dropsA[42][16], dropsA[42][18], dropsA[42][20], dropsA[42][22], dropsA[42][24],
                dropsA[43][0], dropsA[43][2], dropsA[43][4], dropsA[43][6], dropsA[43][8], dropsA[43][10], dropsA[43][12], dropsA[43][14], dropsA[43][16], dropsA[43][18], dropsA[43][20], dropsA[43][22], dropsA[43][24],
                dropsA[44][0], dropsA[44][2], dropsA[44][4], dropsA[44][6], dropsA[44][8], dropsA[44][10], dropsA[44][12], dropsA[44][14], dropsA[44][16], dropsA[44][18], dropsA[44][20], dropsA[44][22], dropsA[44][24],
                dropsA[45][0], dropsA[45][2], dropsA[45][4], dropsA[45][6], dropsA[45][8], dropsA[45][10], dropsA[45][12], dropsA[45][14], dropsA[45][16], dropsA[45][18], dropsA[45][20], dropsA[45][22], dropsA[45][24],
                dropsA[46][0], dropsA[46][2], dropsA[46][4], dropsA[46][6], dropsA[46][8], dropsA[46][10], dropsA[46][12], dropsA[46][14], dropsA[46][16], dropsA[46][18], dropsA[46][20], dropsA[46][22], dropsA[46][24],
                dropsA[47][0], dropsA[47][2], dropsA[47][4], dropsA[47][6], dropsA[47][8], dropsA[47][10], dropsA[47][12], dropsA[47][14], dropsA[47][16], dropsA[47][18], dropsA[47][20], dropsA[47][22], dropsA[47][24],
                dropsA[48][0], dropsA[48][2], dropsA[48][4], dropsA[48][6], dropsA[48][8], dropsA[48][10], dropsA[48][12], dropsA[48][14], dropsA[48][16], dropsA[48][18], dropsA[48][20], dropsA[48][22], dropsA[48][24],
                dropsA[49][0], dropsA[49][2], dropsA[49][4], dropsA[49][6], dropsA[49][8], dropsA[49][10], dropsA[49][12], dropsA[49][14], dropsA[49][16], dropsA[49][18], dropsA[49][20], dropsA[49][22], dropsA[49][24],
                dropsA[50][0], dropsA[50][2], dropsA[50][4], dropsA[50][6], dropsA[50][8], dropsA[50][10], dropsA[50][12], dropsA[50][14], dropsA[50][16], dropsA[50][18], dropsA[50][20], dropsA[50][22], dropsA[50][24],
                dropsA[51][0], dropsA[51][2], dropsA[51][4], dropsA[51][6], dropsA[51][8], dropsA[51][10], dropsA[51][12], dropsA[51][14], dropsA[51][16], dropsA[51][18], dropsA[51][20], dropsA[51][22], dropsA[51][24],
                dropsA[52][0], dropsA[52][2], dropsA[52][4], dropsA[52][6], dropsA[52][8], dropsA[52][10], dropsA[52][12], dropsA[52][14], dropsA[52][16], dropsA[52][18], dropsA[52][20], dropsA[52][22], dropsA[52][24],
                dropsA[53][0], dropsA[53][2], dropsA[53][4], dropsA[53][6], dropsA[53][8], dropsA[53][10], dropsA[53][12], dropsA[53][14], dropsA[53][16], dropsA[53][18], dropsA[53][20], dropsA[53][22], dropsA[53][24],
                dropsA[54][0], dropsA[54][2], dropsA[54][4], dropsA[54][6], dropsA[54][8], dropsA[54][10], dropsA[54][12], dropsA[54][14], dropsA[54][16], dropsA[54][18], dropsA[54][20], dropsA[54][22], dropsA[54][24],
                dropsA[55][0], dropsA[55][2], dropsA[55][4], dropsA[55][6], dropsA[55][8], dropsA[55][10], dropsA[55][12], dropsA[55][14], dropsA[55][16], dropsA[55][18], dropsA[55][20], dropsA[55][22], dropsA[55][24],
                dropsA[56][0], dropsA[56][2], dropsA[56][4], dropsA[56][6], dropsA[56][8], dropsA[56][10], dropsA[56][12], dropsA[56][14], dropsA[56][16], dropsA[56][18], dropsA[56][20], dropsA[56][22], dropsA[56][24],
                dropsA[57][0], dropsA[57][2], dropsA[57][4], dropsA[57][6], dropsA[57][8], dropsA[57][10], dropsA[57][12], dropsA[57][14], dropsA[57][16], dropsA[57][18], dropsA[57][20], dropsA[57][22], dropsA[57][24],
                dropsA[58][0], dropsA[58][2], dropsA[58][4], dropsA[58][6], dropsA[58][8], dropsA[58][10], dropsA[58][12], dropsA[58][14], dropsA[58][16], dropsA[58][18], dropsA[58][20], dropsA[58][22], dropsA[58][24],
                dropsA[59][0], dropsA[59][2], dropsA[59][4], dropsA[59][6], dropsA[59][8], dropsA[59][10], dropsA[59][12], dropsA[59][14], dropsA[59][16], dropsA[59][18], dropsA[59][20], dropsA[59][22], dropsA[59][24],
                dropsA[60][0], dropsA[60][2], dropsA[60][4], dropsA[60][6], dropsA[60][8], dropsA[60][10], dropsA[60][12], dropsA[60][14], dropsA[60][16], dropsA[60][18], dropsA[60][20], dropsA[60][22], dropsA[60][24],
                dropsA[61][0], dropsA[61][2], dropsA[61][4], dropsA[61][6], dropsA[61][8], dropsA[61][10], dropsA[61][12], dropsA[61][14], dropsA[61][16], dropsA[61][18], dropsA[61][20], dropsA[61][22], dropsA[61][24],
                dropsA[62][0], dropsA[62][2], dropsA[62][4], dropsA[62][6], dropsA[62][8], dropsA[62][10], dropsA[62][12], dropsA[62][14], dropsA[62][16], dropsA[62][18], dropsA[62][20], dropsA[62][22], dropsA[62][24],
                dropsA[63][0], dropsA[63][2], dropsA[63][4], dropsA[63][6], dropsA[63][8], dropsA[63][10], dropsA[63][12], dropsA[63][14], dropsA[63][16], dropsA[63][18], dropsA[63][20], dropsA[63][22], dropsA[63][24],
                dropsA[64][0], dropsA[64][2], dropsA[64][4], dropsA[64][6], dropsA[64][8], dropsA[64][10], dropsA[64][12], dropsA[64][14], dropsA[64][16], dropsA[64][18], dropsA[64][20], dropsA[64][22], dropsA[64][24],
                dropsA[65][0], dropsA[65][2], dropsA[65][4], dropsA[65][6], dropsA[65][8], dropsA[65][10], dropsA[65][12], dropsA[65][14], dropsA[65][16], dropsA[65][18], dropsA[65][20], dropsA[65][22], dropsA[65][24],
                dropsA[66][0], dropsA[66][2], dropsA[66][4], dropsA[66][6], dropsA[66][8], dropsA[66][10], dropsA[66][12], dropsA[66][14], dropsA[66][16], dropsA[66][18], dropsA[66][20], dropsA[66][22], dropsA[66][24],
                dropsA[67][0], dropsA[67][2], dropsA[67][4], dropsA[67][6], dropsA[67][8], dropsA[67][10], dropsA[67][12], dropsA[67][14], dropsA[67][16], dropsA[67][18], dropsA[67][20], dropsA[67][22], dropsA[67][24],
                dropsA[68][0], dropsA[68][2], dropsA[68][4], dropsA[68][6], dropsA[68][8], dropsA[68][10], dropsA[68][12], dropsA[68][14], dropsA[68][16], dropsA[68][18], dropsA[68][20], dropsA[68][22], dropsA[68][24],
                dropsA[69][0], dropsA[69][2], dropsA[69][4], dropsA[69][6], dropsA[69][8], dropsA[69][10], dropsA[69][12], dropsA[69][14], dropsA[69][16], dropsA[69][18], dropsA[69][20], dropsA[69][22], dropsA[69][24],
                dropsA[70][0], dropsA[70][2], dropsA[70][4], dropsA[70][6], dropsA[70][8], dropsA[70][10], dropsA[70][12], dropsA[70][14], dropsA[70][16], dropsA[70][18], dropsA[70][20], dropsA[70][22], dropsA[70][24],
                dropsA[71][0], dropsA[71][2], dropsA[71][4], dropsA[71][6], dropsA[71][8], dropsA[71][10], dropsA[71][12], dropsA[71][14], dropsA[71][16], dropsA[71][18], dropsA[71][20], dropsA[71][22], dropsA[71][24],
                dropsA[72][0], dropsA[72][2], dropsA[72][4], dropsA[72][6], dropsA[72][8], dropsA[72][10], dropsA[72][12], dropsA[72][14], dropsA[72][16], dropsA[72][18], dropsA[72][20], dropsA[72][22], dropsA[72][24],
                dropsA[73][0], dropsA[73][2], dropsA[73][4], dropsA[73][6], dropsA[73][8], dropsA[73][10], dropsA[73][12], dropsA[73][14], dropsA[73][16], dropsA[73][18], dropsA[73][20], dropsA[73][22], dropsA[73][24],
                dropsA[74][0], dropsA[74][2], dropsA[74][4], dropsA[74][6], dropsA[74][8], dropsA[74][10], dropsA[74][12], dropsA[74][14], dropsA[74][16], dropsA[74][18], dropsA[74][20], dropsA[74][22], dropsA[74][24],
                dropsA[75][0], dropsA[75][2], dropsA[75][4], dropsA[75][6], dropsA[75][8], dropsA[75][10], dropsA[75][12], dropsA[75][14], dropsA[75][16], dropsA[75][18], dropsA[75][20], dropsA[75][22], dropsA[75][24],
                dropsA[76][0], dropsA[76][2], dropsA[76][4], dropsA[76][6], dropsA[76][8], dropsA[76][10], dropsA[76][12], dropsA[76][14], dropsA[76][16], dropsA[76][18], dropsA[76][20], dropsA[76][22], dropsA[76][24],
                dropsA[77][0], dropsA[77][2], dropsA[77][4], dropsA[77][6], dropsA[77][8], dropsA[77][10], dropsA[77][12], dropsA[77][14], dropsA[77][16], dropsA[77][18], dropsA[77][20], dropsA[77][22], dropsA[77][24],
                dropsA[78][0], dropsA[78][2], dropsA[78][4], dropsA[78][6], dropsA[78][8], dropsA[78][10], dropsA[78][12], dropsA[78][14], dropsA[78][16], dropsA[78][18], dropsA[78][20], dropsA[78][22], dropsA[78][24],
                dropsA[79][0], dropsA[79][2], dropsA[79][4], dropsA[79][6], dropsA[79][8], dropsA[79][10], dropsA[79][12], dropsA[79][14], dropsA[79][16], dropsA[79][18], dropsA[79][20], dropsA[79][22], dropsA[79][24],
                dropsA[80][0], dropsA[80][2], dropsA[80][4], dropsA[80][6], dropsA[80][8], dropsA[80][10], dropsA[80][12], dropsA[80][14], dropsA[80][16], dropsA[80][18], dropsA[80][20], dropsA[80][22], dropsA[80][24],
                dropsA[81][0], dropsA[81][2], dropsA[81][4], dropsA[81][6], dropsA[81][8], dropsA[81][10], dropsA[81][12], dropsA[81][14], dropsA[81][16], dropsA[81][18], dropsA[81][20], dropsA[81][22], dropsA[81][24],
                dropsA[82][0], dropsA[82][2], dropsA[82][4], dropsA[82][6], dropsA[82][8], dropsA[82][10], dropsA[82][12], dropsA[82][14], dropsA[82][16], dropsA[82][18], dropsA[82][20], dropsA[82][22], dropsA[82][24],
                dropsA[83][0], dropsA[83][2], dropsA[83][4], dropsA[83][6], dropsA[83][8], dropsA[83][10], dropsA[83][12], dropsA[83][14], dropsA[83][16], dropsA[83][18], dropsA[83][20], dropsA[83][22], dropsA[83][24],
                dropsA[84][0], dropsA[84][2], dropsA[84][4], dropsA[84][6], dropsA[84][8], dropsA[84][10], dropsA[84][12], dropsA[84][14], dropsA[84][16], dropsA[84][18], dropsA[84][20], dropsA[84][22], dropsA[84][24],
                dropsA[85][0], dropsA[85][2], dropsA[85][4], dropsA[85][6], dropsA[85][8], dropsA[85][10], dropsA[85][12], dropsA[85][14], dropsA[85][16], dropsA[85][18], dropsA[85][20], dropsA[85][22], dropsA[85][24],
                dropsA[86][0], dropsA[86][2], dropsA[86][4], dropsA[86][6], dropsA[86][8], dropsA[86][10], dropsA[86][12], dropsA[86][14], dropsA[86][16], dropsA[86][18], dropsA[86][20], dropsA[86][22], dropsA[86][24],
                dropsA[87][0], dropsA[87][2], dropsA[87][4], dropsA[87][6], dropsA[87][8], dropsA[87][10], dropsA[87][12], dropsA[87][14], dropsA[87][16], dropsA[87][18], dropsA[87][20], dropsA[87][22], dropsA[87][24],
                dropsA[88][0], dropsA[88][2], dropsA[88][4], dropsA[88][6], dropsA[88][8], dropsA[88][10], dropsA[88][12], dropsA[88][14], dropsA[88][16], dropsA[88][18], dropsA[88][20], dropsA[88][22], dropsA[88][24],
                dropsA[89][0], dropsA[89][2], dropsA[89][4], dropsA[89][6], dropsA[89][8], dropsA[89][10], dropsA[89][12], dropsA[89][14], dropsA[89][16], dropsA[89][18], dropsA[89][20], dropsA[89][22], dropsA[89][24],
                dropsA[90][0], dropsA[90][2], dropsA[90][4], dropsA[90][6], dropsA[90][8], dropsA[90][10], dropsA[90][12], dropsA[90][14], dropsA[90][16], dropsA[90][18], dropsA[90][20], dropsA[90][22], dropsA[90][24],
                dropsA[91][0], dropsA[91][2], dropsA[91][4], dropsA[91][6], dropsA[91][8], dropsA[91][10], dropsA[91][12], dropsA[91][14], dropsA[91][16], dropsA[91][18], dropsA[91][20], dropsA[91][22], dropsA[91][24],
                dropsA[92][0], dropsA[92][2], dropsA[92][4], dropsA[92][6], dropsA[92][8], dropsA[92][10], dropsA[92][12], dropsA[92][14], dropsA[92][16], dropsA[92][18], dropsA[92][20], dropsA[92][22], dropsA[92][24],
                dropsA[93][0], dropsA[93][2], dropsA[93][4], dropsA[93][6], dropsA[93][8], dropsA[93][10], dropsA[93][12], dropsA[93][14], dropsA[93][16], dropsA[93][18], dropsA[93][20], dropsA[93][22], dropsA[93][24],
                dropsA[94][0], dropsA[94][2], dropsA[94][4], dropsA[94][6], dropsA[94][8], dropsA[94][10], dropsA[94][12], dropsA[94][14], dropsA[94][16], dropsA[94][18], dropsA[94][20], dropsA[94][22], dropsA[94][24],
                dropsA[95][0], dropsA[95][2], dropsA[95][4], dropsA[95][6], dropsA[95][8], dropsA[95][10], dropsA[95][12], dropsA[95][14], dropsA[95][16], dropsA[95][18], dropsA[95][20], dropsA[95][22], dropsA[95][24],
                dropsA[96][0], dropsA[96][2], dropsA[96][4], dropsA[96][6], dropsA[96][8], dropsA[96][10], dropsA[96][12], dropsA[96][14], dropsA[96][16], dropsA[96][18], dropsA[96][20], dropsA[96][22], dropsA[96][24],
                dropsA[97][0], dropsA[97][2], dropsA[97][4], dropsA[97][6], dropsA[97][8], dropsA[97][10], dropsA[97][12], dropsA[97][14], dropsA[97][16], dropsA[97][18], dropsA[97][20], dropsA[97][22], dropsA[97][24],
                dropsA[98][0], dropsA[98][2], dropsA[98][4], dropsA[98][6], dropsA[98][8], dropsA[98][10], dropsA[98][12], dropsA[98][14], dropsA[98][16], dropsA[98][18], dropsA[98][20], dropsA[98][22], dropsA[98][24],
                dropsA[99][0], dropsA[99][2], dropsA[99][4], dropsA[99][6], dropsA[99][8], dropsA[99][10], dropsA[99][12], dropsA[99][14], dropsA[99][16], dropsA[99][18], dropsA[99][20], dropsA[99][22], dropsA[99][24]]
    
    
    // ######################################## Function to Filter Items ###########################################
    var matchRow = itemArray.find(r => r[0] == dropsB[0])
    var match = matchRow ? matchRow : ""
    if(match[3] == 0) {
        var healingArray = healing.getRange(1,1,healing.getLastRow(),healing.getLastColumn()).getValues()
        var matchID = healingArray.find(id => id[0] == dropsB[0])
        if(matchID) {
            // Do nothing to avoid duplicates
        } else {
            healing.getRange(healing.getLastRow()+1,1,1,58).setValues([match])
        }
    } else if(match[3] == 2 || match[3] == 11 || match[3] == 18) {
        var usableArray = usable.getRange(1,1,usable.getLastRow(),usable.getLastColumn()).getValues()
        var matchID = usableArray.find(id => id[0] == dropsB[0])
        if(matchID) {
            // Do nothing to avoid duplicates
        } else {
            usable.getRange(usable.getLastRow()+1,1,1,58).setValues([match])
        }
    } else if(match[3] == 3) {
        var lootArray = loot.getRange(1,1,loot.getLastRow(),loot.getLastColumn()).getValues()
        var matchID = lootArray.find(id => id[0] == dropsB[0])
        if(matchID) {
            // Do nothing to avoid duplicates
        } else {
            loot.getRange(loot.getLastRow()+1,1,1,58).setValues([match])
        }
    } else if(match[3] == 4 && match[14] == 16) {
        var armorArray = armor.getRange(1,1,armor.getLastRow(),armor.getLastColumn()).getValues()
        var matchID = armorArray.find(id => id[0] == dropsB[0])
        if(matchID) {
            // Do nothing to avoid duplicates
        } else {
            armor.getRange(armor.getLastRow()+1,1,1,58).setValues([match])
        }
    } else if(match[3] == 4 && match[14] == 32) {
        var shieldArray = shield.getRange(1,1,shield.getLastRow(),shield.getLastColumn()).getValues()
        var matchID = shieldArray.find(id => id[0] == dropsB[0])
        if(matchID) {
            // Do nothing to avoid duplicates
        } else {
            shield.getRange(shield.getLastRow()+1,1,1,58).setValues([match])
        }
    } else if(match[3] == 4 && match[14] == 1) {
        var headgearArray = headgear.getRange(1,1,headgear.getLastRow(),headgear.getLastColumn()).getValues()
        var matchID = headgearArray.find(id => id[0] == dropsB[0])
        if(matchID) {
            // Do nothing to avoid duplicates
        } else {
            headgear.getRange(headgear.getLastRow()+1,1,1,58).setValues([match])
        }
    } else if(match[3] == 4 && match[14] == 4) {
        var garmentArray = garment.getRange(1,1,garment.getLastRow(),garment.getLastColumn()).getValues()
        var matchID = garmentArray.find(id => id[0] == dropsB[0])
        if(matchID) {
            // Do nothing to avoid duplicates
        } else {
            garment.getRange(garment.getLastRow()+1,1,1,58).setValues([match])
        }
    } else if(match[3] == 4 && match[14] == 64) {
        var footgearArray = footgear.getRange(1,1,footgear.getLastRow(),footgear.getLastColumn()).getValues()
        var matchID = footgearArray.find(id => id[0] == dropsB[0])
        if(matchID) {
            // Do nothing to avoid duplicates
        } else {
            footgear.getRange(footgear.getLastRow()+1,1,1,58).setValues([match])
        }
    } else if(match[3] == 4 && match[14] == 8 || match[3] == 4 && matchRow[14] == 128) {
        var accessoryArray = accessory.getRange(1,1,accessory.getLastRow(),accessory.getLastColumn()).getValues()
        var matchID = accessoryArray.find(id => id[0] == dropsB[0])
        if(matchID) {
            // Do nothing to avoid duplicates
        } else {
            accessory.getRange(accessory.getLastRow()+1,1,1,58).setValues([match])
        }
    } else if(match[3] == 5) {
        var weaponsArray = weapons.getRange(1,1,weapons.getLastRow(),weapons.getLastColumn()).getValues()
        var matchID = weaponsArray.find(id => id[0] == dropsB[0])
        if(matchID) {
            // Do nothing to avoid duplicates
        } else {
            weapons.getRange(weapons.getLastRow()+1,1,1,58).setValues([match])
        }
    } else if(match[3] == 6) {
        var cardsArray = cards.getRange(1,1,cards.getLastRow(),cards.getLastColumn()).getValues()
        var matchID = cardsArray.find(id => id[0] == dropsB[0])
        if(matchID) {
            // Do nothing to avoid duplicates
        } else {
            cards.getRange(cards.getLastRow()+1,1,1,58).setValues([match])
        }
    } else if(match[3] == 7) {
        var eggsArray = eggs.getRange(1,1,eggs.getLastRow(),eggs.getLastColumn()).getValues()
        var matchID = eggsArray.find(id => id[0] == dropsB[0])
        if(matchID) {
            // Do nothing to avoid duplicates
        } else {
            eggs.getRange(eggs.getLastRow()+1,1,1,58).setValues([match])
        }
    } else if(match[3] == 8) {
        var petArmorArray = petArmor.getRange(1,1,petArmor.getLastRow(),petArmor.getLastColumn()).getValues()
        var matchID = petArmorArray.find(id => id[0] == dropsB[0])
        if(matchID) {
            // Do nothing to avoid duplicates
        } else {
            petArmor.getRange(petArmor.getLastRow()+1,1,1,58).setValues([match])
        }
    } else if(match[3] == 10) {
        var ammoArray = ammo.getRange(1,1,ammo.getLastRow(),ammo.getLastColumn()).getValues()
        var matchID = ammoArray.find(id => id[0] == dropsB[0])
        if(matchID) {
            // Do nothing to avoid duplicates
        } else {
            ammo.getRange(ammo.getLastRow()+1,1,1,58).setValues([match])
        }
    } else if(match[3] == 12) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

As you can see, my array **dropsB** contains 1300 different values, the code below is filtering only the first value on that array **dropsB[0]**, and if I wish to also filter the other 1299 values on **dropsB**, I would have to duplicate more than 100 lines of code each time for **dropsB[1]**, **dropsB[2]**... until **dropsB[1299]**, so my script would become 130,000 lines of code, which would probably be unnecessary and might affect performance.

So, how can I make the function below ######## Function to Filter Items ######## to filter the other 1299 values on my array without an extensive code?

Thank you.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Which is your question `How can I make this code do its function with every value on array? (Apps Script)` or `How can I make it find all items in array dropsB1 without having to write 13 instances of the same code but with different values?`?

Comment: I believe both appreciated member, the array on the title question is exactly the same array as I was referring to in the question of the body on the thread, **dropB1**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You may do this by sharing to us a link of a sample spreadsheet in your post.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that I noticed your reply just now. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot imagine your actual Spreadsheet. So, I modified your script by guessing your Spreadsheet. So, when my proposed script was not useful for your situation, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly testing your situation? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: See  secrets of debugging in [mcve]. You may even find your answer, when trying the first step of "restarting from scratch"

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Tanaike, I will edit question and post link to sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your showing script and your goal, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- In order to retrieve the values using `dropsB1`, I used `fiter` function.
- In your script, each row is appended to each sheet. If your goal is directly achieved, it is required to use `setValues` and `appendRow` are used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will become high. So, in this modification, all values are retrieved in each array. And, the values of each array are put to each sheet using Sheets API. By this, the values can be put to each sheet by one API call. I thought that when Sheets API is used in your situation, the process cost might be able to be reduced.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function GetDrops() {
  var mobItemDB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mobDB = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('mobDB');
  var itemDB = mobItemDB.getSheetByName('itemDB');
  var itemDBLastRow = itemDB.getLastRow();
  var itemDBLastColumn = itemDB.getLastColumn();
  var itemArray = itemDB.getRange(8, 1, itemDBLastRow - 7, itemDBLastColumn).getValues();
  var sheetNames = ['0 Healing', '2-11-18 Usable', '3 Loot', '4a Armor', '4b Shield', '4c Headgear', '4d Garment', '4e Footgear', '4f Accessory', '5 Weapons', '6 Cards', '7 Eggs', '8 Pet Armor', '10 Ammo'];
  var objInit = sheetNames.reduce((o, e) => (o[e] = [], o), {});
  var dropsA1 = mobDB.getRange(3, 37, 1, 26).getValues();
  var dropsB1 = [dropsA1[0][0], dropsA1[0][2], dropsA1[0][4], dropsA1[0][6], dropsA1[0][8], dropsA1[0][10], dropsA1[0][12], dropsA1[0][14], dropsA1[0][16], dropsA1[0][18], dropsA1[0][20], dropsA1[0][22], dropsA1[0][24]];
  var obj = itemArray.filter(([a]) => dropsB1.includes(a)).reduce((o, match) => {
    if (match[3] == 0) {
      o['0 Healing'].push(match)
    } else if (match[3] == 2 || match[3] == 11 || match[3] == 18) {
      o['2-11-18 Usable'].push(match)
    } else if (match[3] == 3) {
      o['3 Loot'].push(match)
    } else if (match[3] == 4 && match[14] == 16) {
      o['4a Armor'].push(match)
    } else if (match[3] == 4 && match[14] == 32) {
      o['4b Shield'].push(match)
    } else if (match[3] == 4 && match[14] == 1) {
      o['4c Headgear'].push(match)
    } else if (match[3] == 4 && match[14] == 4) {
      o['4d Garment'].push(match)
    } else if (match[3] == 4 && match[14] == 64) {
      o['4e Footgear'].push(match)
    } else if (match[3] == 4 && match[14] == 8 || match[3] == 4 && match[14] == 128) {
      o['4f Accessory'].push(match)
    } else if (match[3] == 5) {
      o['5 Weapons'].push(match)
    } else if (match[3] == 6) {
      o['6 Cards'].push(match)
    } else if (match[3] == 7) {
      o['7 Eggs'].push(match)
    } else if (match[3] == 8) {
      o['8 Pet Armor'].push(match)
    } else if (match[3] == 10) {
      o['10 Ammo'].push(match)
    } else if (match[3] == 12) {
      // Do nothing
    }
    return o;
  }, objInit);
  var data = Object.entries(obj).reduce((ar, [name, values]) => {
    if (values.length > 0) {
      ar.push({ values, range: `'${name}'!A${mobItemDB.getSheetByName(name).getLastRow() + 1}` });
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (data.length > 0) {
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate({ data, valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" }, mobItemDB.getId());
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the source values are retrieved from "itemDB" sheet. And, the values are filtered using the values retrieved from "mobDB" sheet. And, the filtered values are split into each sheet, and the values are put using Sheets API.

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot imagine your actual Spreadsheet. So, I modified your script by guessing your Spreadsheet. So, when my proposed script was not useful for your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly testing your situation? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### References:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: First of all thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question, this was indeed a very good approach to what I am trying to do.

If I understood correctly, the modified code will filter all and every single item in the itemDB? Or is it going to only find the items that are actually dropped by each mob in mobDB?

I also edited question and shared link to my sheets for a closer approach.

Comment: Your code worked like a charm, it brought all of the items for the first monster like I required. Thank you very much.

Comment: I was thinking about adding an if statement to check if the row already exist in target sheet, for example, a red plant drops 'stem' and a blue plant also drops 'stem', we pass 'stem' with its properties on '3 loot' table but then when we look for blue plant drops it checks that 'stem' is already in the table. What is the value that I should find? Is it **a**, **e** or **o**??

Comment: @undefined Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your new question. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question?

Comment: Sure, so let's say we are bringing the item 'Stem' from the **itemDB** sheet to the **3 Loot** sheet with the code that you proposed.

But let's say the item 'Stem' was already in my **3 Loot** sheet, so there is no need to add a duplicate row.

My question is how to check if item row already exists in target sheet, I was thinking about something like this:

if (match[3] == 0 && MATCH DOES NOT EXIST IN '0 Healing') {
  o['0 Healing'].push(match)
    } else if (match[3] == 3 && MATCH DOES NOT EXIST IN '3 Loot') {
  o['3 Loot'].push(match)
    }

@tanaike

Comment: @undefined Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But from your reply, I think that the question of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Yes definitely, can dooo. However I have asked multiple questions in a short period of time, reason why I have to wait a little bit before posting a new questions. But yes! Definitely, I will post it immediately when I can. I'll talk to you soon~! Thank you again for your willingness to help!!

Comment: @undefined Thank you for replying. When I saw your new question, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: Do you know why your modified script is sorting the information with the IDs from smaller to larger when returning values to filtered sheets? @Tanaike

I am trying to get them in the order of the array because the original itemDB is already sorted by ID.

Comment: @undefined About your 3rd question of `Do you know why your modified script is sorting the information with the IDs from smaller to larger when returning values to filtered sheets?`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your 3rd question. Can I ask you about the detail of your 3rd question?

Comment: @undefined I think that the reason that I cannot resolve your various questions immediately is due to my poor English skill. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I have to study English more.

Comment: No worries at all @tanaike, I have made some changes to my original post to make my question clearer.

Comment: @undefined Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But from your updated question, I think that the 2nd and 3rd questions are new issues, and those are different from your question. So can you post them as new questions? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new questions, users including me can think of them. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?